# Tomcat stops responding

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I am using Tomcat 7 for deploying my application. Many a times I encounter a situation where tomcat runs fine and after some time just stops responding. By not responding I mean the web pages are not loading. I check my log files and do not see anything unwanted there. Checked with jvisualvm for memory and other stuff and even those are file... I am not sure if this is something because of my code or because of some configuration that I have made on JVM/Tomcat.. Please help

The following are my parameters set

```
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1280M
-XX:PermSize=256M
-XX:MaxPermSize=320m
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-Dappviewx_install_dir=/home/myDir
-Dappviewx_web_port=5004
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-verbose:gc
-Xloggc:/home/myDir/verbosegc.log
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/home/myDir/properties/log4j.properties_web
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=4970
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dorg.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export=true
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/myDir/web/apache-tomcat-web/endorsed
-Dcatalina.base=/home/myDir/web/apache-tomcat-web
-Dcatalina.home=/home/myDir/web/apache-tomcat-web
-Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/myDir/web/apache-tomcat-web/temp
```

Comment: You didn't mention whether your catalina.err and catalina.out are error free. Is that true?

Comment: The catalina logs dont have anything much to tell... They are without any errors

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have within my /etc/init.d/tomee startup shell script:

CATALINA_OPTS="-server -Xmx3096m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=$CATALINA_HOME/logs"

You already have a heap size set and permgen, but what you don't have is the heapdump. Make sure you have CATALINA_HOME set or replace with an absolute path.

The other thing to consider, is removing some of the nonstandard options that you have. You might be suffering from a bug that is related to an option you have specified.

In other words, start doing a process of elimination.